# Where to find oil in Civ5?

Tags: civilization-5

After I researched Biology I found 2 sources of oil and after that turn the oil signals dissappeared and i dont know where these sources are.
How i can identify them ? I have a World like map and i have all America dominated.

Thanks

Comment: Down in the lower left corner of the map there's a button for a 2D perspective and a scroll icon.  Click the scroll and make sure 'Show Strategic Resources' is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Oil is a strategic resource in Civilization 5 that can be found on Desert, Snow, Tundra or Coast. You need to make an oil well on land to get at it or an offshore platform to get at it on the sea.